# Plotting a specific time interval in Matlab

Tags: matlab, plot

I have a signal, let's say x, with a dimension of 60000x1 and i'm plotting it in time, t.

```
x = % a 60000x1 signal

fs = 1000;

t = 0:1/fs:(length(x)-1)/1000; % i want to plot the signal in seconds and it's correct
```

so if i `plot(t,x);` it plots my signal in seconds (from 0 to 60s)

question is: How do i plot a specific time interval? (e.g. from 3 to 5s)

i tried `plot(t(3:5),x(3:5));` and it plots x based on its original dimension i guess. so it will work at `plot(t(3000:5000),x(3000:5000)` but my x label is incorrect.

Any help will be appreciated! Thank you!!

Comment: yeah but isn't there any way to plot it based on t?

Comment: Based on t? you could do something like `t1=3;t2=5` and then `plot(t(t1*fs:t2*fs),x(t1*fs:t2*fs)` maybe?

Comment: What do you mean by your `xlabel` is incorrect ?

Comment: yeah. i guess this is ok for now! it's working so what the hell right. 

Thanks for the heads up, ander!!

Comment: yes. found it: xlim! Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways to achieve this. The first one is to define a subset of values:

```
I = 3000:5000;
plot(t(I), x(I));
```

The second method is to use the `xlim` setting:

```
plot(t,x);
xlim([3 5]);
```

which will set the bounds of the plot at 3 and 5 seconds.